# Setting limits for x-axis with date hours mins secs data

Tags: pandas, datetime, matplotlib, time-series, timestamp

I have a dataframe as below:

```
                           o        h        l        c  volume  complete  \
time                                                                        
2020-01-16 00:00:00  1.30400  1.30401  1.30394  1.30401       7      True   
2020-01-16 00:01:00  1.30398  1.30398  1.30394  1.30396       6      True   
2020-01-16 00:02:00  1.30394  1.30402  1.30380  1.30402      20      True   
2020-01-16 00:03:00  1.30400  1.30411  1.30397  1.30411       8      True   
2020-01-16 00:04:00  1.30414  1.30414  1.30411  1.30414       7      True
```

that continues for several months.

I am using matplotlib as follows:

```
ax1 = plt.subplot2grid((6,1), (0,0), rowspan=5, colspan=1)
ax2 = plt.subplot2grid((6,1), (5,0), rowspan=1, colspan=1,sharex=ax1)
ax1.plot(data.index, data['c'])
ax2.plot(data.index, data['volume'])
ax1.set_xlim([data.index.date(2020, 1, 16), data.index.date(2020, 1, 17)])
plt.show()
```

and I get the following traceback:

```
    ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-67-ad1471a25939> in <module>
      6 #ax1.plot(data.index, data['l'])
      7 ax2.plot(data.index, data['volume'])
----> 8 ax1.set_xlim([data.index.date(2020, 1, 16), data.index.date(2020, 1, 17)])
      9 
     10 plt.show()

TypeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object is not callable
```

What is the correct way to define xlim ? Ideally in datetime values (eg. 2020-01-16 00:00:00) but date values would also do (eg. 2020-01-16).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[**`Axes.set_xlim`**](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.set_xlim.html) wants the `left` and `right` bounds as separate params, not list/array.

For the timestamps, you can use [**`Pandas.timestamp`**](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Timestamp.html).

This should do what you want:

```py
ax1.set_xlim(pd.Timestamp('2020-01-16 00:00:00'), pd.Timestamp('2020-01-17 00:00:00'))
```